# multiply function with two parameters and add 100 to the result

Tags: javascript

I have some problems. Maybe it will be easy but I really don't know what should I do to go forward.

I have exercise to create a function called `calculate_total` with two parameters: `num_items` to represent the number of items and `price` to represent the price per item. The function has to multiply these two parameters and add 100 to `result(shopping costs)`. All I have is this:

```
function calculate_total(num_items, price){
    return calculate_total=num_items*price
    var total=calculate_total+100
    return total;
}
```

I am writing it in `index.js`. I don't know how it should look.

Comment: as you are returning before adding so 100 is not getting added to the total and also you are using two return statement which is wrong in ur scenario. so remove 1st return keyword and use var/ let then it will work properly

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, you return to early, because you return only the product, without adding the surcharge to it.

The [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) ends the function. The following code is not executed of the function.

A short approach is just to add the value and return the result.

```
function calculate_total(num_items, price) {
    return num_items * price + 100;
}
```

BTW, a good formatting of the code helps to read the code and by using proper indentations, you get a visual representation of nested statements. Fun fact, if you reach the other side of the editor, you should think about over putting some code into own function and reduce complexity.

Comment: I know this is moot since it will return the same result because of  *"order of operations"* -- BUT --  I always like to paren my math so that it's obvious which math is being executed first -- IE `return ( num_items * price ) + 100;`

Answer (score 1):

As a function, you can try this:

```
function calculate_total(num_items,price){
    return num_items * price + 100;
}
console.log(calculate_total(x, y));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```js
function calculate_total(num_items, price) {
    return num_items * price + 100;
}
```

Or a more concise way to do the same

```js
const calculate_total = (num_items, price) => num_items * price + 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you return something from a function the function exits and the code after that does not go through.
Just do

```
function calculate_total(num_items, price){
   var calculate_total = num_items * price
   var total = calculate_total + 100

return total;
}
```

Replacing return with var does the job.